# Kill the current Toast Notificatoin

Tags: nativescript, toast

Is there any option to kill/hide/cancel current Toast Notification under Android 10 + TNS?

I want to show the meaning of some words by tapping on them, but under Android 10 user needs to wait until previous Toast Notification times out until he/she can see the next one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is found!

just store the `Toast.makeText( var )` in a variabile like myToast and use `cancel()` function to remove it.

```
let myToast = Toast.makeText( var ); // show() function shouldn't be used here!
myToast.show(); 

...

myToast.cancel();
```